# Getting the list of binded services for an app

Tags: cloud-foundry

Referring the docs: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/managing-services.html#list

How to get the list of services that are bind to an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do it using

```
cf env <app_name>
```

It returns a list of applications that are bound to this app

```
System-Provided:
{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "external-dependency-service": [ .. ], 
  "sso": [ .. ], 
  "<any other service type>": [<list of services>]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight-forward cf CLI command to list the services instances bound to an app.

You could use `cf create-app-manifest YOUR_APP`, which will create a manifest file with a [`services` block](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#services-block) listing all bound service instances, if any exist.

You can also call the CC API (using `cf curl /v2/apps/:guid/service_bindings`). See [API documentation here](http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/272/apps/list_all_service_bindings_for_the_app.html).

Comment: I do have a manifest.yml file... but thats an external file. I want to delete app and then recreate it and create all the services that are binded to it. Getting list of binded config services from an external file is something that I should be looking for?